# "End of Central Directory record could not be found" - NuGet in VS community 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2015

I am getting an error when i try to install any package from the NuGet in VS community edition 2015.

```
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29' with respect to project 'ClassLibrary1', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29'
Resolved actions to install package 'Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14' does not exist in project 'ClassLibrary1'
Package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14' does not exist in folder 'C:\Users\441793\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ClassLibrary1\packages'
System.IO.InvalidDataException: End of Central Directory record could not be found.
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.Init(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen)
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Encoding entryNameEncoding)
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode)
   at NuGet.Packaging.NuGetPackageUtils.ExtractPackage(String targetPath, FileStream stream)
   at NuGet.Packaging.NuGetPackageUtils.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<<InstallFromStreamAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.<ExecuteWithFileLocked>d__0`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.<ExecuteWithFileLocked>d__0`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at NuGet.Packaging.NuGetPackageUtils.<InstallFromStreamAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3.GlobalPackagesFolderUtility.<AddPackageAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3.DownloadResourceV3.<GetDownloadResourceResultAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.PackageDownloader.<GetDownloadResourceResultAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__42.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__42.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.<ExecuteActionsAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.<PerformActionAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
========== Finished ==========
```

Error message i receive is in the Error List tab is

```
End of Central Directory record could not be found
```

I tried from Console application to Class libraries and getting this error for all packages i tried to install.

NuGet Version is : 3.0.60624.657

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Could this be caused by trying to unzip a *.gz or *.7z file?

Comment: @jp2code I found out the problem. It was because the package manager trying to unzip a corrupt *.zip file (exception was not handled). The file became corrupt due to the firewall policy of my corporation which blocked the nuget domain and resulting in 1kb file. Thanks for your interest

Comment: Try installing using Package Manager Console

Comment: @Curiousity Thanks for the advice. However, this was due to a corrupt zip file being downloaded. nuget package manager couldn't open it. I was behind a corporate firewall which blocked the nuget domain which caused this corruption.

Comment: There is closed, but still reproducible bug on nuget for such error message https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5076

Answer (score 18):

Go into your solution folder and delete your "packages" folder. You'll need to right-click your solution and select "Manage packages" and click the "Restore" button at the top of the screen where it tells you the packages are missing.

Answer (score 11):

Remove folder 'packages' in your project folder. Wipe data from these folders:

`%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages`

`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\NuGet\v3-cache`

`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\dnu\cache`

Then open solution and right-click to solution tree and click 'Restore NuGet Packages'.

Answer (score 3):

Try next:

```
D:\src\build>nuget locals -clear all
Clearing NuGet HTTP cache: C:\Users\dzmitry\AppData\Local\NuGet\v3-cache
Clearing NuGet cache: C:\Users\dzmitry\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
Clearing NuGet global packages cache: C:\Users\dzmitry\.nuget\packages\
WARNING: Local resources partially cleared.
WARNING: Failed to delete 'C:\Users\dzmitry\.nuget\packages\'.
WARNING: Failed to delete 'C:\Users\dzmitry\.nuget\packages\fsharp.data.xmlprovider\2.3.14159\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.DesignTime.dll'.
Clearing local resources failed: one or more errors occured.
```

Comment: Clearing the NuGet cache solved this problem for me as well, in this case when using Visual Studio 2017 and package references rather than packages.config.

Comment: If you have got a local NuGet package folder (package source on your disk) where your locally created packages are stored, make sure to clear that folder as well. That solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error just now from another silly cause: I'd run out of disk space! If these solutions aren't working for you, that's another thing to check.

Answer (score 1):

Got this error when trying to open my own NuGet package. My NuGet package was based on a .7z file instead of a .zip file.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue. I recently experienced a similar problem.
Opened cmd window as admin. 
CD to nuget exe folder
I ran nuget update -self 
Above steps resolved my issue