# SonarQube 6.5 - Not able to trigger TFS Build Definition

Tags: sonarqube, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, sonarqube-scan

I have added the SonarQube - Begin Analysis and End Analysis tasks to my TFS Build definition. I have my SonarQube server up and running. I added a SonarQube Service endpoint and added it while configuring the SonarQube Begin analysis task.

However when I trigger the build, it fails throwing the below error -
**'Unhandled Exception: System.IO.InvalidDataException: End of Central Directory record could not be found**.'

Any idea what the issue might be?
I am using SonarQube 6.5 version.

```
 Starting: Get sources

 Running tasks

 Starting task: Fetch the Quality Profile from SonarQube

 Executing the powershell script: c:\Program
 Files\TFS2015Agent\tasks\SonarQubePreBuild\1.0.34\SonarQubePreBuild.ps1
 SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 1.1 Default properties file was not
 found at C:\Program
 Files\TFS2015Agent\tasks\SonarQubePreBuild\1.0.34\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.1\SonarQube.Analysis.xml

 Pre-processing started. Preparing working directories... Checking for
 updates... Unhandled Exception: System.IO.InvalidDataException: End of
 Central Directory record could not be found. 


 at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory() 
 at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.Init(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen)
 at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Encoding entryNameEncoding)
 at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open(String archiveFileName, ZipArchiveMode mode, Encoding entryNameEncoding)
 at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(String sourceArchiveFileName, String destinationDirectoryName, Encoding entryNameEncoding)
 at SonarQube.Bootstrapper.BuildAgentUpdater.TryUpdate(String hostUrl, String targetDir, ILogger logger)
 at SonarQube.Bootstrapper.Program.PreProcess(IBuildAgentUpdater updater, IBootstrapperSettings settings, ILogger logger)
 at SonarQube.Bootstrapper.Program.Execute(String[] args, IBuildAgentUpdater updater, ILogger logger)
 at SonarQube.Bootstrapper.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Maybe this is a [Nuget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493537/end-of-central-directory-record-could-not-be-found-nuget-in-vs-community-201) problem. Does the build succeed when both SonarQube tasks are disabled?

Comment: Yes the Build succeeds with the SonarQube tasks removed.

Comment: Part of the error seems to be missing. Can you double-check that you didn't omit part of the error log?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam - Actually that is the complete error message. The build just gets hung after throwing this error, and eventually I have to cancel the build. The only thing which I did not mention in this error was the Syncing Repository,Workspace Name details in the 'Starting:Get Sources' section.

Comment: @Sammy What about the event viewer? Are there any related info/logs there? Also try to remove the SonarQube extension, clean caches, then reinstall the [latest version of the extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube), then try it again.

Comment: I will give this a try.

Comment: That actually helped! Thanks. So seems like everytime we upgrade to a new version of SonarQube, we will need to install the updated version of the scanner as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the issue, I had to download the [latest version of the SonarQube build tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube) in TFS. The easiest option is to navigate to the Admin TFS Extension Page on the server and use it to download and install the updated SonarQube extension.

[image]

Once that was done, I triggered the TFS build and was able to get past this error.